# Trying to create a touch swipe and delete feature on mobile web. No libraries other than jquery

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Trying to implement a touch swipe feature only using jquery and css3.

No jQuery mobile please, just jquery.

I would like to press and hold any of the boxes that have the word "swipe" and move them left or right in mobile.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;

}

li {
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Swipe</li>
  <li>Swipe</li>
  <li>Swipe</li>
  <li>Swipe</li>
  <li>Swipe</li>
  <li>Swipe</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [jQuery UI - Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) 
Also, there is no support for touch devices from jQuery side. There are some user created addons like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648676/505842), but i don't really know if this one is working. I'll notify you if i find any other ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery Ui Sortable.

Add jquery.touchpunch plugin to make jquery ui work on mobile device.