# Draggable Elements That Push Others Out Of Way on MOBILE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been able to create Draggable Elements That Push Others Out Of Way using the following resource:

[Draggable Elements That Push Others Out Of Way](https://codepen.io/Snarkie3/pen/XmvRQM)

```js
$(".slides").sortable({
     placeholder: 'slide-placeholder',
    axis: "y",
    revert: 150,
    start: function(e, ui){
        
        placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
        ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
        $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        
        ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
            height: ui.item.outerHeight() + 15
        }, 300);
        
        placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight + 15).animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
            $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
        });
        
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();
        
        console.clear();
        var tabSlides = [];
        $('.slides li').each(function() {
          tabSlides.push($(this).prop('class').split(' ')[1]);
        });

        $.each(tabSlides, function(index, value){
          console.log(`${value}`);
        });
    },
});
```

The script works very well on desktop but I couldn't get t working on mobile. Based on my online search it probably requires a jquery patch or some kind of handle?
What change should be made on the script to make it mobile-friendly?

Comment: you need touch support for jquery ui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641590/jquery-ui-sortable-how-to-get-it-work-on-ipad-touchdevices

Comment: I saw that question before but the link to the solution (touchpunch.furf.com/content.php?/sortable/default-functionality) is broken. Do you know what change I should make?

Comment: check this my demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vishnunls/gv9Lzsd4/3/

Comment: Thanks for that but I faced a new issue: When the blocks are at the bottom of the page and I try to drag the blocks up on mobile, the screen scrolls up instead of the block. What's you suggestion?