# Issues using jQuery UI Sortable with Bootstrap 5 responsive page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-5, jquery-ui-sortable

Has anyone used the [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) widget on a Bootstrap 5 responsive page?

My page has a series of `<div class="col-lg-6">` elements, so it shows two per row.

The sorting works. But I have the following issues:

1. If I drag an item on the left over to the item on the right, nothing happens. It only swaps the two items if I also drag it down.
2. If I use a mobile device layout (1 item per row), nothing drags or sorts at all.

I created a CodePen for this but I was unable to find a CDN with the appropriate jQuery UI components. If anyone knows where those are, I can add them. My CodePen is at https://codepen.io/softcircuits/pen/QWBWwwJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This seems to be working after setting the `tolerance: 'pointer'` option.
2. This appears related to the detection of touch events (vs mouse events), which jQuery UI doesn't support. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641590/jquery-ui-sortable-how-to-get-it-work-on-ipad-touchdevices).

Also, scroll wasn't working for me. This was due to the `<body>` having a `overflow-x: hidden` style.